# cakephp-2.0 simplest ajax link with jshelper

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-helper

I want to create the most basic ajax link there is in Cakephp 2.0.

In **index.ctp** i have

```
 <?php
echo $this->Js->link('myLink', array('controller'=>'technologies', 'action'=>'view'), array('update'=>'#success'));
?>
 <div id="success"></div>
```

in **TechnologiesController.php** i have

```
public function view(){
    $this->set('msg', 'message');
    $this->render('view', 'ajax'); 
}
```

and in **view.ctp** i have

```
<?php echo $msg;?>
```

Instead of setting the view in the success div, it navigates to the http://local.cake.com/technologies/view page to display the message.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like a javascript error....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default scripts are cached, and you must explicitly print out the cache. To do this at the end of each page, include this line just before the ending  tag:

```
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); // Write cached scripts
```

I am using this at the end of my default.ctp in the Layouts Folder

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to set $components = array('RequestHandler') in your controller

Answer (score 1):

So, in total the code would look like this - and it works for me (CakePHP 2.2.4):

index.ctp:

```
<?php
echo $this->Js->link('myLink', array('controller'=>'technologies', 'action'=>'view'), array('update'=>'#success'));
?>

<div id="success"></div>

echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
```

Thank you a lot, this helped me understand how things work in 2.0 and above :)

Answer (score 0):

try `$this->autoRender = FALSE;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to put this:

```
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
```

somewhere - for example right below the `$this->Js->link` call.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I just put this:

```
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
```

it work for me, hope i will for you